# What's a good place to recruit japanese language learners?

Tags: discussion

This wasn't appropriate for the main site, and may not be appropriate here. Just wondering if there's someplace on this site, or another site, that might be good for recruiting some fresh blood into the fan translation scene?

I do a lot of work fan translating video games in a particular community that's been around over 15 years, and I've noticed that recent requests for translators haven't been turning up results. There are translators in the scene that will get around to these things eventually, myself included, but I figure there are soooo many language learners, some of them must have an interest in doing fan translating for fun. Any suggestions?

Comment: Beside scouting Discord servers, irc servers, and reddit I don't really have any idea.